# How to derive an list of structs from any struct type - getting from interface{} to a variable length slice []interface{}

Tags: arrays, go, reflection, slice

I try to implement a function taking (any) structure, returning an array of those structures. ReturnArrayOfStory show the idea with a fixed type struct type.

trying to do the same for any type with function ReturnArrayOfX and reflection fails at compile time.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)
type story_t struct {
    LANGUAGE string
    SPECIES  string
}

func ReturnArrayOfStory(x story_t) []story_t {
    x1 := x
    var a1 []story_t
    a1 = append(a1, x1)
    a1 = append(a1, x1)
    a1 = append(a1, x1)
    return a1
}

func ReturnArrayOfX(x interface{}) []interface{} {
    x1 := x
    v1 := reflect.ValueOf(&x1).Elem()
    a1 := []reflect.TypeOf(&x1)
    //  var a1 []x
    a1 = append(a1, x1)
    a1 = append(a1, x1)
    a1 = append(a1, x1)
    //return a1
    return a1
}

func main() {

    var as1 []story_t

    s1 := story_t{"EN", "Prince of Persia"}

    as1 = ReturnArrayOfStory(s1)
    //as1 := ReturnArrayOfX(s1)
    for i := 0; i < len(as1); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%02d %+v\n", i, as1[i])
    }

    as2 := ReturnArrayOfX(s1)
    //as1 := ReturnArrayOfX(s1)
    for i := 0; i < len(as2); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%02d %+v\n", i, as2[i])
    }

}

a1 := []reflect.TypeOf(&x1)
main.go:25:8: reflect.TypeOf is not a type
```

*This is a simplified scenario. In reality, I like to read a multitude of struct types from an external  data source like a database.*

- How can I came to my goal with ReturnArrayOfX?
- List item Is this possible? If not,**why**?

Comment: ok, strictly grammatically I see now your point: SliceType = "[" "]" ElementType. ArrayType = "[" ArrayLength "]" ElementType.Thus my notation grammatically returns a slice and you are right. I change to title of the post accordingly.

Comment: It's more accurate now. A bit redundant to say "variable length slice", though, since slices are, by definition, variable length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem:

First: if you want to return a slice of a type using reflection:

```
// You cannot return []interface{}, because this function will return [](type of x), and that is not []interface{}
func ReturnArrayOfX(x interface{}) interface{} {
    x1 := x
    a1 := 
// this creates *[](typeOf x)
reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(x)))
// Append the first element to *[](typeof x)
// after this, a1 now points to a slice, not to a slice *
    a1 = reflect.Append(a1.Elem(), reflect.ValueOf(x1))
    a1 = reflect.Append(a1, reflect.ValueOf(x1))
    a1 = reflect.Append(a1, reflect.ValueOf(x1))
    //return [](typeof x)
    return a1.Interface()
}
```

You can use this as:

```
as2 := ReturnArrayOfX(s1)
arr:=as2.([]story_t)
for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%02d %+v\n", i, arr[i])
}
```

Second: you can return []interface{} without reflection:

```
func ReturnArrayOfX(x interface{}) []interface{} {
   ret:=make([]interface{},0)
   ret=append(ret,x)
   ret=append(ret,x)
   ret=append(ret,x)
}
```

Then you need to deal with each element of the array:

```
as2 := ReturnArrayOfX(s1)
for i := 0; i < len(as2); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%02d %+v\n", i, as2[i])
    data:=as2[i].(story_t)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, both solutions work for me, whereas I prefer the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic slice conversion function:

```
// convertSlice copies the slice in src to the slice pointed to by pdst. 
// The concrete values in src must be assignable to the dst elements.
func convertSlice(pdst interface{}, src interface{}) {
    dstv := reflect.ValueOf(pdst).Elem()
    srcv := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    dstv.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(dstv.Type(), srcv.Len(), srcv.Len()))
    for i := 0; i < srcv.Len(); i++ {
        dstv.Index(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(srcv.Index(i).Interface()))
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
// Convert []story_t to []interface{}

s0 := []story_t{{"EN", "Prince of Persia"}, {"EN", "Karateka"}}
var s1 []interface{}
convertSlice(&s1, s0)

// Convert []interface{} containing story_t to []story_t

var s2 []story_t
convertSlice(&s2, s1)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pXrpZPPQIQQ).